# How do I make an idempontent shell in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible and I have a little problem trying to make idempotent a shell execution. The first I do is install ***python-apt package*** because I need it to use the apt module for install others packages. But every time that I run my *playbook* the shell task always runs and I want to make it idempotent. Here is my shell task:

```
- name: install pyton-apt
  shell: apt-get install -y python-apt
```

And here is the output, always running the above task:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml 

PLAY [docker] ***************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [10.0.3.240]

TASK: [docker | install pyton-apt] ******************************************** 
changed: [10.0.3.240]

TASK: [docker | install unzip] ************************************************ 
ok: [10.0.3.240]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
10.0.3.240                 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the ansible `apt` module to install `python-apt`, which will be idempotent out of the box: http://docs.ansible.com/apt_module.html

E.g.

```
- name: install python-apt
  apt: name=python-apt state=present
```

(Note using the apt module should automatically install `python-apt` on the remote host so I'm not sure why you would need to manually install it, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4079)

Edit: If for some reason you can't use the inbuilt `apt` module to install python apt, the `shell` module provides the `creates` parameter to help make it idempotent.

```
- name: install python-apt
  shell: apt-get install -y python-apt >> /home/x/output.log creates=/home/x/output.log
```

What this means is that the shell module will not run if `/home/x/output.log` already exists.

Comment: At the time of this writing people are reporting in [issue 4079](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4079) that `apt` module still does not auto-install `pyton-apt` dependency.