# How to get Ansible to run a step ONLY 1x

Tags: ansible

I have a Ansible step as below

```
- name: pipenv install of bluebird workers, pg helpers, boto helpers
       shell: pipenv --python 3.6 install "bluebird-workers>=3.0.24" "pg_helpers>=1.0.9" "boto_helpers>=1.0.28"
```

Above step keeps re-running on each run of the playbook. How to make above step to run just once. I want the semantic where it installs 1x (and another task does the update-- that task should re-run each time)

Comment: You want your playbook to be idempotent, which is generally how Ansible works. The problem is that you're using the `shell` module which doesn't support that. Try to use for example the `pip` module.

Comment: But if you insist on using `shell`, try adding the `creates` option as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577429/1446479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Avoid using the shell module if at all possible!**

The `shell` module is *not* idempotent; it has no way of knowing if it ran prior since you could run literally *anything* from the shell.

A far cleaner approach would be to use the [pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html) instead.

```
tasks:
- name: Install python libraries.
  pip:
    name:
      - bluebird-workers>=3.0.24
      - pg_helpers>=1.0.9
      - boto_helpers>=1.0.28
    virtualenv: /path/to/your/virtualenv
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an artifact that can be searched, such as a file.  Check if the file exists in your Ansible task and if it's there do not run a task.

A simple playbook to demonstrate is:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
     - name: test if file is present
       stat:
          path: /var/pip_installed
       register: stat_result

     - name: Install something
       shell: ls -l > /var/pip_installed creates=/var/pip_installed
       become: true
       when: stat_result.stat.exists == false
```

You'd replace the `ls -l` with your shell command.

Here's the Output for two runs:

**Run one**

> $ ansible-playbook  test_ps.yml
>    [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [localhost] ****
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] ****
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [test if file is present] ****
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Install something] ****
>   changed: [localhost]
>
> PLAY RECAP ****
>
> localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

**Run two**

> PLAY [localhost] ****
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] ****
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [test if file is present] ****
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Install something] ****
>   skipping: [localhost]
>
> PLAY RECAP ****
>
> localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

You can also search on a file you know is installed with `pip`, or create your own file.